# Selenium IDE 2.4.0 hover effect on google map?

Tags: testing, selenium, automation, automated-tests

I am using Selenium IDE 2.4.0, to test a Website That uses Google Map, How can i test if a particular element on the map or Page is having a hover effect on mouse-over?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use "firebug" to track the elements of a website.
It comes a plugin for firefox.

Comment: I know firebug tracks that element but, something called as Wicket changes the id of that element which is not found by selenium ide

Comment: And the object is on Google map and firebug detects canvas not the object on the Google map